# How to change the spinner prompt background?

Tags: android

As I am developing android application, where I want to change spinner prompt background color and text color?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a question here

Comment: `I want to change spinner prompt background color`

Comment: That is a statement, not a question.

Comment: Please check this thread: 




http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198666/how-to-change-a-spinners-list-background-color-in-android

Comment: @MarioStoilov , statement itself has question :)

Answer (score 0):

to change the text color and style :
make an xml layout spinner_text.xml contains:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:textSize="18sp"
android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

then in your class setup the ArrayAdapter to use it :

```
     Spinner yourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerID);
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),      R.layout.spinner_text, yourStingArray);
     yourSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

to change the spinner background in xml :

```
    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/sCategory"
        android:entries="@array/angleList"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_shape"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_shape" />
```

and do whatever you need in drawable: spinner_shape

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/colorFour" />
<stroke
    android:color="@color/colorTwo"
    android:width="2dp" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="4dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="4dp"
    android:topRightRadius="4dp" />
```

android:popupBackground will do the drop items list look
android:background will do the spinner look

Comment: I want to change the background of the prompt of the spinner?

Comment: what do you mean by prompt? if its the drop list so its  android:popupBackground="@drawable/spinner_shape"