# Change Spinner background programmatically

Tags: android, xml, android-spinner

I have some Spinners that need to change the background. So, I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/iconodesplegableactivar"
 android:state_enabled="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/iconodesplegable"
android:state_enabled="false" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
</selector>
```

I have no problems with the Spinners set in layout file, but some spinners are generated dynamically.

How could I use that xml in a spinner generated dinamically? The setBackground() method doesn't allow you to set xml as an argument, and I can't add an ID to the XML.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_file_name);`

Comment: No, it is not. Check: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int)

Comment: @Fustigador setBackgroundDrawable() method is deprecated, not setBackgroundResource() method.

Comment: You are right, my fault. setBackgroundDrawable() is the deprecated method. Sorry.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198666/how-to-change-a-spinners-list-background-color-in-android), and something which I'm using as well:

If you're creating `Spinner` dynamically then use this:

```
// to change background of the popup list
  spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_background);

// to change the `Spinner` background
  spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

And here is `spinner_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
</shape>
```

Comment: seems really non-intuitive to have to create an xml file just to tell a control to paint the background colour. I'm not saying you are wrong, rather that this area of android seems unnecessarily complicated. Possibly due to a thin API?

Comment: If you're not banging your head against the wall or pulling your hair out during Android development, then you aint doing it right lol.

Comment: @Journey now-a-days it is recommended that you support API 16 at minimum not below it. [According to Android official OS market share](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) only 0.14% devices still use below API 16.

Comment: I am working on an update of an accounting app which is already on playstore and more than 50% users use API 16 or below.  Any ways thank you for the information.

Answer (score 3):

Add a LinearLayout as its background.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/YOUR_BACKGROUND_COLOR">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/pattern_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_file_name)` to set resource as a background. This method is not deprecated. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Write in your code:

```
spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.spinner_background);
```